# How to convert single list's elements in form of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i want below list as dictionary

```
sample_list=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

expected dictionary shown below

```
out_dict = {'A':'B','C':'D'}
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use:

```
dict(zip(sample_list[::2], sample_list[1::2]))
```

where `zip` creates the key, value pairs for the new dictionary.

---

a variant using iterators (and therefore avoid making copies of your list) is to iterate in paris (ehrm... *pairs* as Matthias pointed out in the comments)  over your list with `zip(it, it)` and then create the dictionary from that:

```
it = iter(sample_list)
dct = dict(zip(it, it))
```

---

in **python>=3.8** you will be able to use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) and do what you need with this nice one-liner

```
dct = dict(zip(it := iter(sample_list), it))
```

Comment: "iterate in paris" is nice. ;)

Comment: hmmm. now i can't fix the typo anymore. so i will pretend i meant it this way! you should go iterate in paris! it's beautiful in spring.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following dictionary comprehension:

```
{x:y for x,y in zip(sample_list[::2], sample_list[1::2])}
# {'A': 'B', 'C': 'D'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming that the list has an even number of elements:

```
{ sample_list[i] : sample_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(sample_list) - 1, 2) }
```

This solution has the advantage that it doesn't create intermediate lists under Python 3.x, in Python 2.x just replace `range` with `xrange`.

Answer (score 3):

**This Example can cope with uneven lists (which would normally crash python)**

```
sample_list= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H']
output = {}
for i in range(0,len(sample_list),2):
    #print(sample_list[i],sample_list[i+1])
    if (i+1) < len(sample_list): #Dont need this line, just avoids python
    #crashing if the list isn't even.
        temp = {sample_list[i]:sample_list[i+1]}
        output.update(temp)
    else:
        print("ERROR: LIST NOT EVEN, WILL NOT INCL. Last Item.")
print(output)
```

Produces this output:

```
{'A': 'B', 'C': 'D', 'E': 'F', 'G': 'H'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with an iterator:

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

it = iter(lst)
{k: next(it) for k in it}
# {'A': 'B', 'C': 'D'}
```

Comment: You took my original idea! Nice.

Comment: @prosti How is about `{k: v for k, v in zip(it, it)}`?

Comment: @prosti First you need to initialize your iterator `it = iter(lst)`.

Comment: yes, you need to initialize the iterator. and as i mentioned, in python>=3.8 we will be able to do this: `dct = dict(zip(it := iter(sample_list), it))`. how nice is that?!

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
n = { lst[n]:lst[n+1] for n in range(0, len(lst), 2)}
n
```

Comment: isn't that just [Óscar López's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038382/4954037)?

Comment: This is my answer. I haven't cheated ;)

Comment: i'm not saying you copied it (you clearly did not); it is just the same answer and his was ~15min earlier.

Comment: Well I came late to the party. :]